# What's it called when you generate all permutations with replacement for a certain size and is there a formula to calculate the count?

Tags: permutations

If I have a set of numbers $\{1,2\}$ the permutations are $\{1,2\}$ and $\{2,1\}$. We can calculate the number of permutations using $\dfrac{n!}{(n-r)!} = \dfrac{2!}{0!} = 2$.

However, if I instead say I want to find all permutations of the set $\{1,2\}$ for a size $2$ with replacement (*not sure if there is a more terse/less ambiguous name for this*), then we get
$\{1,1\}, \{1,2\}, \{2,1\}, \{2,2\}$. The count is $4$. **Is there a formula for calculating this**?

Now imagine my set of numbers is $\{1,2,3\}$. If I want to find all permutations of the set $\{1,2,3\}$ for a size $2$ with replacement, I get
$\{1,1\}$
$\{1,2\}$
$\{1,3\}$
$\{2,2\}$
$\{2,1\}$
$\{2,3\}$
$\{3,3\}$
$\{3,1\}$
$\{3,2\}$
and the count is $9$.

Further, is there a simple derivation of the formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen these called **the $n$-tuples of $S$**. The number of them is $|S|^n$, because there are $|S|$ options for each of the $n$ positions.

For example, $(1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3)$ are the $2$-tuples of $\{1,2,3\}$. Notice that there are $3^2=9$ of them.

Also, notice that I used (parenthesis) on these instead of $\{$set brackets$\}$, because we want the pairs to be ordered.

Comment: yeah i was just coming on to post the formula is simply |S|^n  after I realised one way to get them is to 'count up' like you would in binary or decimal. Despite having an engineering degree with a fair amount of math I don't think it ever clicked between {} meaning set vs () for ordered tuple. That is what you were getting at in your last point right?

Comment: Yes. For example, $(1,2)$ is different from $(2,1)$, but $\{1,2\}$ is the same thing as $\{2,1\}$. With parenthesis, order matters; with set brackets, it doesn't.

Comment: thanks for your input. consider question answered. thanks again